# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable for user input

Tags: python, string, typeerror

I always get "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable" when trying to get user input in my first if statement.

I tried searching online and on stackoverflow, but only found fixes that didn't work for me, such as making sure the "()" are in the right place.

```
import os
from uuid import uuid4

f = open("address.txt","w+")

input = input("Do you already have an address (y/n): ")

if input == "y":
    address = input("Please enter your address: ")
    f.write(address)
    f.close() 

if input == "n":
    address = "some default address"
    f.write(address)
    f.close()
```

Weird thing is, the first input works without any errors and for line 9 (address = ...) I get "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are assigning `str` to `input` variable which is conflicting with your `input()` function.

Try like this:

```
import os
from uuid import uuid4

f = open("address.txt","w+")

my_input = input("Do you already have an address (y/n): ")

if my_input == "y":
    address = input("Please enter your address: ")
    f.write(address)
    f.close() 

if my_input == "n":
    address = "some default address"
    f.write(address)
    f.close()
```

Comment: Thanks! Everything is working now

Answer (score 2):

You cant use the word "input" as a variable name:

try changing `input = input("Do you already have an address (y/n): ")` to
`inpt = input("Do you already have an address (y/n): ")`